# How to customize object detection using cv2.dnn_detectionModel method

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning, raspberry-pi, object-detection

is there any way to customize object detection from my script. If yes, how to do it, do I need to install anything? Please provide step by step or video guide.

Anyway, I'm using Raspberry Pi to do it. So it best free GPU, and able to done so inside raspberry pi.

Below this script, it workable for me, just that I need detect specific thing which not included in "coco.name", "ssd_mobilenet".

Example: I want to detect "SKII Toner" instead appear "bottle" I want it to be "SKII Toner"

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

#Threshold setup
thres = 0.3 # Threshold to detect object
nms_threshold = 0.2

#camera setup
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
#cap.set(3,1080)
#cap.set(4,1920)
#cap.set(10,300)

#standard configuration setting up
classFile = "coco.names"
classNames = []
with open(classFile,"rt") as f:
        classNames = f.read().rstrip("\n").split("\n")

#print(classNames)
configPath = "/home/pi/darknet/ssd_mobilenet_v3_large_coco_2020_01_14.pbtxt"
weightPath = "/home/pi/darknet/frozen_inference_graph.pb"

net = cv2.dnn_DetectionModel(configPath,weightPath)
net.setInputSize(320,320)
net.setInputScale(1.0/ 120)
net.setInputMean((120, 120, 120))
net.setInputSwapRB(True)

while True:
    success,img = cap.read()

    img = cv2.flip(img, 0)

    classIds, confs, bbox = net.detect(img,confThreshold=thres)
    bbox = list(bbox)
    confs = list(np.array(confs).reshape(1,-1)[0])
    confs = list(map(float,confs))
    #print(type(confs[0]))
    #print(confs)

    indices = cv2.dnn.NMSBoxes(bbox,confs,thres,nms_threshold)
    #print(indices)

    for i in indices:
        i = i[0]
        box = bbox[i]
        x,y,w,h = box[0], box[1], box[2], box[3]
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y),(x+w,h+y), color=(0,255,0),thickness=1)
        cv2.putText(img,classNames[classIds[i][0]-1].upper(),(box[0]+10,box[1]+30),
            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,1,(0,255,0),1)

    cv2.imshow("Output",img)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Comment: I don't fully understand your question.. do you want to detect a new class "SKII Toner" (I don't even know what it is) ?

Comment: @rok Good Morning Rok, yes i would like to detect new classes,  instead of using coco.names.

Answer (score 0):

Since based on the comments you want to detect new classes, the only way is either to take a pre-trained detection model that already detect the desired class (if any) and see if the accuracy suits your needs, OR even better take a a model pre-trained on a big dataset (e.g COCO) and fine-tune it on a dataset labeled for you class of interest. You will need the dataset for this, and based on your class you may find something already available on the net or will you have to collect one. A good starting point could be the [Tensorflow Object Detection API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection), which provides pre-trained models on COCO and a relatively easy-to-use APIs to fine tune on a new dataset.